# Additional bags on Qatar Airways?

Tags: luggage, airlines, qatar-airways

I will travel next month from Brisbane, Australia to Amman by choosing Qatar airline.

How much will I pay per kilogram, because I have around 15kg. And my ticket economic ticket just 30kg.

Comment: Your ticket allows you 30kg, you have 15kg? What's the problem?

Comment: Did you really mean to put 150kg?

Answer (score 1):

30kg is the upper limit allowed by your ticket. Even if you have less, you pay the same price.

Comment: I'm wondering if he means he has 15kg OVER the 30kg limit, but it's unclear...

Comment: Yes I was just thinking the same thing.